# How to change preferred mode xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I have multiple mode outputed when using `xrandr --verbose` command, as follow:

```
1920x1080 (0x1c3) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
h: width 1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew 0 clock 67.50KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125 clock 60.00Hz

1920x1080 (0x1c4) 325.080MHz +HSync +VSync *current
h: width 1920 start 1944 end 1976 total 2056 skew 0 clock 158.11KHz
v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1098 clock 144.00Hz

1920x1080 (0x1c5) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width 1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew 0 clock 135.00KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125 clock 120.00Hz

1920x1080 (0x1c6) 272.250MHz +HSync +VSync
h: width 1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew 0 clock 123.75KHz
v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125 clock 110.00Hz
```

However the preferred one is the one with clock 60.00Hz i would like to et the preferred one as the one with clock 144.00Hz, thanks.

I already tried to put in Section `"Monitor"` in `xorg.conf`

```
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_144 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
```

Comment: Is the name of your mode really `1920x1080_144 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}`? Maybe you should use only `Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_144"`.

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
cvt 1920 1080 144
```

and you will get a `ModeLine`, which you can use in `xrandr` or in `xorg.conf`. The output of `cvt` is:

```
# 1920x1080 143.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 169.35 kHz; pclk: 452.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
```

Otherwise

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 144
```

should work, too.

---

Additional information:
Try adding the following to `xorg.conf`:

```
Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_144.00"
```

Optionally add

```
Option "UseEDID" "false"
Option "UseEDIDFreqs" "false"
```

if you don't want your computer to use any other resolution received with EDID.

Comment: Already tried to add in xorg.conf, didn't change anything.. and xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 144: Rate 144.00 Hz not available for this size, but my refresh rate is already 144Hz the thing is this is not the preferred mode, and i dont know how to set it as preferred..